# Prove that $\sqrt{a_1} + \sqrt{a_2} +\cdots+ \sqrt{a_n}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\sqrt{a_1}, \sqrt{a_2} ,\cdots, \sqrt{a_n}$ are irrationals and $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are integers $>1$.
I didn't find any proof for this exercise. Please help!!

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: It would seem you didn't learn anything from your previous question, and still haven't shown any effort to your questions. If you had a question about something specific from the proofs in the duplicates to your previous question, you should ask them instead.

Comment: This might be useful for you next time. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Counter example: $$\sqrt{7-4\sqrt3}+\sqrt{7+4\sqrt3}=4$$

Comment: That's just $(2-\sqrt 3)+(2+\sqrt 3)$. I realise the question doesn't explicitly rule out such counter-examples, but the obvious unstated assumption is that the $a_i$ are rational. (And I see that while I was writing this, the OP has made this explicit.)

Comment: Exactly. The given conclusion does not follows from the given hypothesis.

Comment: @Bumblebee Unfortunately, an initial edit by another user to add MathJax accidentally removed the OP's explicit statement the $a_i$ were integers $ \gt 1$. The later edit by the OP put this requirement back into the question text.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Thank you for the information.